# jQuery warning: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead

Tags: jquery

this is sindhuri,I receive the following warning in my Google Chrome console:
event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.
jquery1.9.1 version i am using.

```
<script>
window.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    window.jQuery('#hideshow').click(function () {
        window.jQuery('#message').toggle(function () {
            window.jQuery('#hideshow').text('Show');
            window.jQuery('#message').hide();
            alert("message hide succeesfully");
        }),
        function () {
            window.jQuery('#hideshow').text('Hide');
            window.jQuery('#message').show();

            alert("message show succeesfully");
        }
    });
});
</script> <a href="#" id="hideshow">Hide</a>
```

BeforeUnloadEvent has a returnValue attribute. Setting returnValue to a non-empty string in an event handler causes the user agent should ask the user to confirm that they wish to unload the document. This is equivalent to returning a non-empty string in the EventHandler

Answer (score 4):

It's a [bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320)

This is only a warning message your code will still work.

Answer (score 4):

this is not a bug...

just use the latest version thats going to come out soon (1.11) and you'll be fine

this has a  [jquery.com open ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/14320) :

> The bug is fixed in what will become 1.11/2.1. The duplicate bug
>   ticket #14282 explains this. It also explains that older versions of
>   jQuery will give this warning eternally.

Answer (score -1):

Code will work but in some condition another event is fire because of that warning. And your output will effect somewhere in view page(Probably with jquery ajax call).